# Chart templates, color schemes and font sizes

Tags: templates, charts, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm trying to automate some PowerPoint charts, but I'm having problems preserving some formatting.

When I add a chart using a chart template, the chart doesn't use the slides color scheme, but rather the colors it was saved with. It doesn't help to change the color scheme for the slide - the chart isn't updated. To make the chart update to the color scheme of the slide, I have to clear formatting for the chart. The problem with doing this is that all font sizes are automatically set to 18pt. I cannot find any easy way restore the font sizes for the chart without saving all sizes before calling clear, and set them back after clearing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the Format Painter function it may or may not work depending on a variety of factors from my quick look on the net (google it for lots of articles).

Also if you've done one chart you should be able to copy the formatting from one chart to another using the paste special option as mentioned here http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/there-format-painter-equivalent-use-many-charts-t3611646.html .

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not sure it'll work for my use, but I'll sure look into it the following week. Would probably speed my application up by a factor of 2 while being able to delete some code.